# SQL orders without a record with an item_category of 'b' or 'd'

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, having

This is a data quality query. I want to see if there are any orders without a record with an item_category of 'b' or 'd'.

An order consists of many records. It is fine to have records with other item categories as long as within the order there is at least one
record where item_category in ('b', 'd')

But an order without a ('b', 'd') record would be a problem and I want to know that it is there. This would be an example:

| order_nbr | item_category | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | a | 12342 |
| 7 | c | 89999 |

So given this dataset

| order_nbr | item_category | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 11111 |
| 1 | b | 888888 |
| 1 | a | 124235 |
| 2 | c | 124356 |
| 2 | a | 567567 |

A correct query would only return order_nbr 2.
It would not return order_nbr 1 because order_nbr 1 contains a record with an item_category of 'b'

My first thought was something like this:

```
SELECT order_nbr FROM table
where item_category not in ('b', 'd')
group by order_nbr
```

But this doesn't work because that returns both 1 and 2.

The imperative logic is actually quite simple, here's some pseudocode:

```
//Get the "good" orders
let goodOrders = []
for (let order of orders){
    for(let record of order.records){
        if(record.item_category === 'b' OR 'd'){
            goodOrders.push(record.orderNbr)
            break;
        }
    }
}

//then just compare all orders with goodOrders to find the bad orders
let badOrders = []
for(let orderNbr of orderNbrs){
    if(!goodOrders.contains(orderNbr)){
        badOrders.push(orderNbr)
    }
}
```

Engine is Athena, so CTE's are allowed, but not much more.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `having`:

```
SELECT order_nbr 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY order_nbr
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN item_category IN ('b', 'd') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

This yields order numbers that do not have category b nor category d.

If you want entire rows that correspond to these orders, we can use window functions instead:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        max(case when item_category in ('b', 'd') then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by order_nr) has_cat_b_or_d
    from mytable t
) t
where has_cat_b_or_d = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *not exists* which usually will yield the best performance.

```
select * 
from t
where not exists (
  select * from t t2 
  where t2.order_nbr = t.order_nbr 
    and t2.item_category in ('b','d')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG I can't believe it was that easy... I think I just needed to write this post (b/c I wasn't "seeing" the different sets I needed)

```
with goodOrders as (
 select order_nbr from orders where item_category in ('b', 'd')
),

allOrders as (
select distinct order_nbr from orders
)

select a.order_nbr from allOrders a
left join goodOrders g
on g.order_nbr = a.order_nbr
where g.order_nbr is null
```

Comment: `having` is the right way to go.

Comment: Yep, I always forget about ````having````